# Fatal error: Call to undefined method UsersController::setSubject()

Tags: joomla-3.x, jmail

I am getting the following error message on my Joomla 3 site:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method UsersController::setSubject()

I used `JMail::sendMail` before I used `JUtility::sendMail` in version 1.5.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`setSubject()` is a function that belongs to the `JMail` class, **not** `UsersController`.

So assuming you want to set the subject for your email, you can use the following:

```
$mailer->setSubject('Subject Here');
```

For more information on Joomla's mail feature, have a read of the following:

http://docs.joomla.org/Sending_email_from_extensions

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Lodder thank you for the answer I got it now.